# How do you get N(N+1) from N+1 + N + 1 + ... + N + 1 + N + 1?

Tags: math, sequences

How does:

```
    1 +   2 + ... + N-1 +   N
 +  N + N-1 + ... +   2 +   1
  ---------------------------
 N+1 + N+1 + ... + N+1 + N+1
```

equal N(N + 1)?  Shouldn't it be 4N + 4 or 4(N + 1)?

Comment: And where is your programming question?

Comment: @Doc Brown, can you *please* stop saying 'Jigawatts'.

Comment: Is the question how the sum of 1 to N is N(N+1)? It's actually N(N+1)/2.

Comment: doc brown: programming is basically an applied form of maths, so let's be generous.

Comment: @MSN, this is a specific question on my way to understanding that.

Comment: @pavium: Wait 'til I get my Flux-capicitor working again ;-)

Comment: @Carsten: by that argument you can justify almost any math question here on SO. By the way, you might have noticed, I gave the OP an serious answer.

Comment: @Cartsen: Math is basically applied logic, which is pretty much like philosophy. Hey, I'm going to ask a philosophical question now, it's programming related! Yes, we use math sometimes, but that isn't the point of the site. Maybe something related to algorithm analysis, but not pure math.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is N(N + 1).

Because you have N number of (N+1) terms.

Comment: Oh my god, that is the most elegant answer i've ever seen. Well done. +1

Answer (score 4):

If `N` is 4, sure. Otherwise you need to fill in the rest of the elided values that the ellipses represent.

Answer (score 3):

i assume your notation means row 1
+ row 2 = row 3?

in this case, look at the columns. Each column of the first 2 rows adds up to n+1. there are n columns. thus row 1 + row 2 = n*(n+1)

Answer (score 2):

Read the part about the early years of [Carl Friederich Gauss here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss). He solved almost the same problem when he was in primary school.

Comment: A similar but different question, actually.